# Migration from wxWidgets 2.8.12 to wxWidgets 3.0.2 - features.h

Tags: wxwidgets

I have recently migrated my project from wxWidgets 2.8.12 to 3.0.2. I am using Eclipse as my IDE under Windows 7 OS. The GCC version is 4.6.2.

I have successfully compiled debug and release versions of wxWidgets 3.0.2 and integrated to Eclipse. I compiled my project and I got the error in features.h file saying missing ")". When I read the purpose of features.h, to my understanding it was meant for compatibility with previous versions of wxWidgets so I have deleted everything in features.h and then compiled my project and now it compiles with no errors and everything in my project functions fine when I run the binary.

By the way, I had the same problem with TDM compilers as well. I have also rebuild the index of Eclipse in case there were remnants from wxWidgets 2.8.12 which could confuse the compiler but the problem with features.h remained there until I deleted everything in features.h.

My question is: By deleting the features.h, am I going to run into a problem in the future or will wxWidgets function normally?

Best regards,

Comment: You really need to give the exact error message and its location.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that.
Find out where the real problem lies. There are a lot of people that successfully build wxW with gcc.
The best and easiest test is to build wxW, then build 'minimal' sample. Any error when doing that?

features.h is there for a purpose; by deleting its contents, the symbols there may become wrongly [un-]defined. Further more, if you have deleted contents of features.h *after* you had compiled wxW but *before* compiling your project, then that is a completely wrong build.